# Using relative urls with window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using below JS code to open new window by populating dynamic generated code..

```
function OpenWindow(obj) {
    var w = window.open();
    var stored = $(obj).parent().find("div").html();
    w.document.title = "New Window";
    w.document.URL = "hello.com/dummypage.html"; //how to assign the url to the newly opened window
    $(w.document.body).html(stored);
    return false;
}
```

Relative urls used in this document say for `img src`, in this document is not working.

```
<tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><img id='imglegend' src='/images/Legend.jpg'></td></tr>
```

**EDIT:**

I populate the content dynamically using javascript, just need a valid url in the brower window, to make my hyperlinks & image source ref to work.

P.S. The page pointed out in the js code, doesn't have physical existance.

Answer (score 16):

***how to assign the url to the newly opened window***

You need to pass and URL to `window.open()`

```
window.open('http://www.google.com');//will open www.google.com in new window.
window.open('/relative_url'); //opens relatively(relative to current URL) specified URL
```

Or,

```
function OpenWindow(obj) {
    var w = window.open();
    w.location = "hello.com/dummypage.html"; //how to assign the url to the newly opened window
}
```

Or,
You can even say,

```
w.location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org");
```

Refer [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)

Comment: Thanks, but in my case full url is not known, can I give relative path?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would open a window giving all the parameters in the function like:

```
window.open('yoururl','title','some additional parameters');
```

But you could do it like what you did but you used the wrong variable to add your url. It should be `w.document.location.href`:

```
var w = window.open();
w.document.title = "New window";
w.document.location.href = "hello.com"; //how to assign the url to the newly opened window
$(w.document.body).html(stored);
return false;
```

Comment: `w.document.location.href = "hello.com";` will redirect that opened page to hello.com.

Comment: Yes. And that is what OP wants.

Comment: @putvande No I do not want that. I populate the content dynamically using javascript, just need a valid url in the brower window, to make my hyperlinks & image source ref work.

Comment: No OP wants to open a window with specified URL..Can you check my update code if I am doing right?

Comment: @Abhijeet did you ever find a solution to this? i have the same thing going on

Comment: @AustinBurk Honestly, don't rememember what I had been trying to do. What is your scenario. Can post as a new question, will try to answer.

Comment: @Abhijeet I figured it out - there is apparently an HTML tag called <base> which you can use to set the hostname when using relative URLs. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp